# sqlite error al insertar datos con python

Tags: python, sqlite3

He intentado insertar datos en mi base de datos sqlite pero no lo logro, la base crea un registro pero no contiene los datos, este es mi códido:

```
import sqlite3


class Base:
    def abrir(self):
        conexion=sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/luis/Desktop/pythonYsqlite3/bd1.db")
        return conexion

    def alta(self, datos):

        cone=self.abrir()
        cursor=cone.cursor()
        sql=("""insert into new (id, ref, desc) values (?, ?, ?)""")
        cursor.execute(sql, datos)

        cone.commit()
        cone.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucion: despues de probar, verifique que las variables se pasaban en la sentencia sql "insert" pero estas estaban vacias. Encontre un conflicto de nombres de variables repetidas usadas en 2 funciones de la misma clase: def carga_datos(self) y def consulta_ref(self).

Soluciones modificando los nombres en una de ellas. Las variables en cuestion: self.**orden**=tk.StringVar(), self.**ref**=tk.StringVar() y self.**des**=tk.StringVar().

les dejo el codigo completo para que lo vean y comenten si gustan alguna aclaracion mas formal. Muchas gracias

```
class Formulario:
def __init__ (self):
    self.dato=data1.Base() # instancia de modulo data1 ??????????????????????????????

    self.ventana1 = tk.Tk()
    self.ventana1.title('planilla')
    self.ventana1.geometry('800x650+300+5')

    self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)
    self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    
    # ESTILO /// STYLE
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("TLabel", font=('Calibri', 14, 'bold'))
    style.configure("TEntry", relief="flat", padding=10)

    self.carga_datos()
    self.consulta_ref()
    self.listado_completo()
    self.ventana1.mainloop()

def carga_datos(self):
    self.pagina1 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text='carga de datos')

    self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text="DATOS")        
    self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)

    self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="N.O.")
    self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
    self.orden=tk.StringVar() # OJO establezco variable de tipo cadena
    self.entry_nro_orden=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.orden, font=('Calibri', 14, 'bold'))
    self.entry_nro_orden.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")

    self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="REFERENCIA")        
    self.label2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
    self.ref=tk.StringVar()
    self.entry_referencia=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.ref, font=('Calibri', 14, 'bold'))
    self.entry_referencia.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="w")

    self.label3=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="DESCRIPCION")        
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
    self.des=tk.StringVar()
    self.entry_descripcion=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.des, font=('Calibri', 14, 'bold'))
    self.entry_descripcion.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4, ipadx=200)

    # COMPLETAR PARA LA CARGA DE DATOS

    self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Confirmar", command=self.agregar)
    self.boton1.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
    self.entry_nro_orden.focus_set()



def agregar(self):
    
    datos = (self.ref.get(), self.des.get())
    print(datos)

    self.dato.alta(datos)
    mb.showinfo("Información", "Los datos fueron cargados")

    self.orden.set("")
    self.refe.set("")
    self.des.set("")
class Base:
def abrir(self):
    conexion=sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/luis/Desktop/proyecto2/otradb.db")
    return conexion

def alta(self, datos):

    cone=self.abrir()
    cursor=cone.cursor()
    sql="insert into new (id, ref, desc) values (NULL, ?, ?)"

    cursor.execute(sql, datos)
    #cursor.execute("delete from new") # OJO BORRA TODO REGISTRO
    cone.commit()
    cone.close()
```